# Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (500)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce this [boxplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw4Ph.png) from a linear regression model output. my model and the code I used is below. I am getting this error "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (500)." What am I doing wrong? Please help!

```
out <- lm(L_SHUCK ~ L_VOLUME+CLASS, data = mydata)

r <- residuals(out)

ggplot(out , aes (x = CLASS , y = r, group = CLASS)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

You can't really just put in the output of the `lm` object to do this. You need to do something along these lines:

```
out = lm(mpg ~ wt + as.factor(am), mtcars)
r = residuals(out)
mtcars$residuals = r

ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = as.factor(am), y = residuals))
```

I think a good ggplot2 tutorial would help you understand what is going on exactly, e.g. [this one I wrote](http://stcorp.nl/R_course/tutorial_ggplot2.html).

Comment: Excellent introduction. Thank you for sharing the link.

Comment: @UweBlock thanks, good to hear that the tutorials work for you!

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Thank you for the tutorial. it's working now.